# ¿Cómo convierto la lista ASCII a binario y viceversa? O ¿Cuál sería una manera más eficiente de manejar estas lista?

Tags: java

Intento crear un programa pequeño que a partir de texto, éste se convierta a binario y viceversa.

Mi problema recae en que pude avanzar un poco para que este me convierta de texto a binario, pero no encuentro modo de empezar la segunda parte, la de convertir de binario a texto.

Además, reitero que puedo tener probablemente muchos errores de principiante y me gustaría saber cuál sería una buena forma de utilizar las listas ya creadas, si tienen algo por mencionar entorno al código o si tienen ideas para poder mejorar el código.

```
   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String ruta = "\\Users\\Manuel\\Desktop\\Trabajos\\2 Año\\Programacion orientado a objetos\\Ruta de archivos\\Intentodepasarprogramacion";
        File archivo = new File(ruta);
        BufferedWriter bw;

        List<Integer>ascii;
        List<String>binario2;

        ascii=new ArrayList<>();
        binario2=new ArrayList<>();

        int binarios=0;
        int numero, exp, digito;


        try{
            if(archivo.exists()) {
                bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(archivo));
                String letras ="Ana Graciela Montelongo Arzate", n = null;
                int x=0;
                for (int i=0; i<letras.length(); i++){
                    x=letras.charAt(i);
                    n=Integer.toBinaryString(x);
                    binario2.add(n);
                    ascii.add(x);
                }
                bw.write(letras+ascii+binario2);
            }
            else{
                bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(archivo));
                String letras ="Ana Graciela Montelongo Arzate", n = null;
                int x=0;
                for (int i=0; i<letras.length(); i++){
                    x=letras.charAt(i);
                    n=Integer.toBinaryString(x);
                    binario2.add(n);
                    ascii.add(x);
                }
                bw.write(letras+ascii+binario2);
            }
            bw.close();
        }
        catch (IOException errorDeFichero){
            System.out.println("Ha habido problemas: " +errorDeFichero.getMessage() );
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static String[] toBynary(String str){
    char[] chars = str.toCharArray();//pasamos a un array de caracteres
    String[]bins = new String[chars.length];//creamos un nuevo array con la longitud del otro
    for(int i = 0;i < chars.length;i++){
        int c = chars[i];//pasamos el caracter a entero
        String bin = Integer.toBinaryString(c);//pasamos en entero a binario
        bins[i] = bin;//agremagos al el binario al array
    }
    return bins;//retornamos el array
}
```

[enter link description here](http://foros.cristalab.com/obtener-el-numero-binario-de-char-string-en-java-t23403/%22Fuente%22)